# How to solve "No visible @interface for 'FIRInstanceID' declares the selector 'token'" in ios ionic build

Tags: ios, objective-c, ionic4

I am facing this error when build app in ios.
Please help me..Thanks in advance.

```
- (void) getToken:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command 
{ 
    NSLog(@"get Token");
    [self.commandDelegate runInBackground:^{
        NSString* token = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
        CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:token];
        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
    }];
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem, do you find solution?